# What GUI tool to make CMYK datavisualisation

Tags: graphs, vector-graphics, presentation, printing

When designing for print it would be nice to be able to select the colors in CMYK values. This way the user can control the black levels and not rely on RGB to CMYK conversions, which can be problematic for presentation graphics and uniformity with other assets. Thus being able to use actual black ink, or not using it at all is problematic.

Now, most tools out there only support RGB color. So far i have tested the usual suspects Excel, Open office, Mathematica*, Matlab,  Matplotlib... The only tool I find does this is illustrator and its graphing possibilities are a bit limited and requires a LOT of manual work.

All of these produce RGB only, forcing a workflow that looks like:

```
    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
+-> |  Data    | -> | Plot app | -> |  fix up  | -> | Pub app  | --+
|   +----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+   |
|                                                                  |
+------------------------ Data changes (sigh) ---------------------+
```

This is very very unhealthy since the data WILL change**. Since the fix up is a bit error prone it requires either jump of faith, custom scripting (which is fragile) or manual intervention. In fact the Industry standard approach is to, drum roll, draw the frigging graph manually! Yep that's right, insane I know.

So what application actually supports outputting presentation graphics with CMYK values to the vector graphics output (PDF, EPS)?

- Input format does not matter
- Price does not matter
- OS does not matter
- All it really needs is to support CMYK values on output format, preferably vector. (this pretty much restricts the format to EPS, and PDF though cmyk svg could be possible)
- Anything with a decent GUI is ok

* Mathematica used to be able to do PDF files with CMYK output but this hasn't worked for a while.

** Usually at 23:55 when it needs to be in print at 6:00. Meaning the poor designer needs to work a overnight.

Comment: What OS must such software run on, and how much you'd be willing to pay if it came to that? What is the input format? What other features (except for color management) should the software have?

Comment: @Izzy does not matter, i estimated that lack of such software is causing lost productivity in tune of about a 100,000 euros per year in the building i work in (bt ist conservative number might be easily 10 or 20 times that). Let alone across the globe

Comment: Please include that with your question. And don't forget the other details I've asked for. We can only give good recommendations if we understand what's being asked for :)

Comment: @Izzy Sure I just suspect such an application does not exist.

Comment: How about Indesign?

Comment: @EricShain If i can drop in a data into it and graphs come out  then sure. Feels more like a circumvention scheme to the fact that almost no competent graphing tool can make cmyk data come out.

Comment: Evidently, Illustrator has a graphing tool although it may not suit your purposes.

Comment: @EricShain yeah i said so in my post.

Comment: I think the issue is that color on a computer is intrinsically RGB as that is what the displays use. Conversion to CMYK is output device dependent and is handled in color management tools either in the operating system of within the program for those designed for print output like Indesign.

Comment: @EricShain Yeah but even RGB is device dependent. So no worries i just want to set the CMYK value. That means the software does not need to know how to convert to CMYK, just form CMYK to RGB if even that. I understand why this feature is uncommon, but i dont understand why its nonexistent.